# Lua find a key from a value

Tags: lua

I'm working with this:

```lua
chars = {
    ["Nigo Astran"] = "1",
    ["pantera"] = "2"
}
    
nchar = chars[$name] + 1
```

The variable `$name` will give me a string that I'm logged in to, in this case: `"Nigo Astran"`
and `nchar` has the value `"2"` if I'm in `"Nigo Astran"`, and so on. I believe you get the idea.

Now, I want to get the **key** from the value, for example:

when `nchar` is `"2"` it should give me `"pantera"` as the key. I'm just not getting the value of the key.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you find yourself needing to get the key from the value of a table, consider inverting the table as in

```
function table_invert(t)
   local s={}
   for k,v in pairs(t) do
     s[v]=k
   end
   return s
end
```

Comment: well atm im using this code
function get_key_for_value( t, value )
  for k,v in pairs(t) do
    if v==value then return k
  end
  return nil
end


now im finding another problem, when my table ends, and returns a nil i want it, to loop from the first value, cant do that yet <,<

Comment: The for loop is missing a do.

Comment: I'd recommend using `ipairs` rather than `pairs`, as it preserves the order of the original table.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there is anything more efficient than looping over the entries in the table using `pairs` and comparing the keys.

you can do that using something like this

```
function get_key_for_value( t, value )
  for k,v in pairs(t) do
    if v==value then return k end
  end
  return nil
end
```

Then you'd use it like this:

```
local k = get_key_for_value( chars, "1" )
```

Comment: ok that works but sadly, i cant do like
<pre>
nchar = (chars[$name])+1
<code>
 get_key_for_value( chars, nchar )
will be nil idk why, that was my problem at the start xD

Comment: got it i did it with tostring()

love you anyways <3

Answer (score 0):

the best way to do that is like this

```
 local autoreply={
['hey']='hi',
['how are u']='am fine what about u?',
['how r u']='am fine what about u?',
['how are you']='am fine what about u?',
['sleep']='rockabye bayby good dreems',
['السلام']='وعليكم السلام ورحمة الله وبركاته',
}
local keys={'hey','how are u','how r u','how are you','sleep','السلام'}
function getValueFromKey(table,key)
  for k,v in ipairs(keys)do
  if string.find(string.upper(key),string.upper(v)) then return table[v] end
  end
   return false
end
```