# Get table key name from value

Tags: lua, key, lua-table

I'm trying to get table key name from a value.
`tostring` only returns `table: XXXXXXXXX`

I tried some functions but nothing work.

```
config = {
    opt1 = "etc..."
}
players = {}

function openMenu(playerName, configTable)
    players[playerName] = Something to get Table Key...

    -- read the table and create a gui not yet made
end
```

And next, if I do this :

```
print(players[playerName])
```

I want to get this output :

```
"config"
```

Comment: P.S : That need to work with table's table (myTable = { config = {} })

Comment: possible duplicate of [Lua find a key from a value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7925090/lua-find-a-key-from-a-value)

Comment: no it isn't, i found how to

Comment: It would seem that no one quite understands your question, as the answer and upvotes here would suggest. Could you  clarify the difference in your question?

Comment: I'm gonna re-explain. I got a variable and I want to get his name (the variable is a table)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to iterate over all `pairs` of the table and return the key if the value is equal. Note that this will only return one binding, even if multiple keys can lead to the same value:

```
function find(tbl, val)
    for k, v in pairs(tbl) do
        if v == val then return k end
    end
    return nil
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way, unfortunately, is to store the keys as a value to read them later.
For convenience of any sort of further exports or parsing, prepend them with underscore (or anything to your liking) aka `_key` so you can omit them.

Answer (score -1):

```
table.find(t, value [,start_index]) -> [key or nil]
```