# What is the difference between indexing an array and a dictionary?

Tags: arrays, dictionary, lua

From my understanding, an array is a simple table of values, such as `local t = {"a","b","c"}`, and a dictionary is a table of objects, such as `local t = {a = 1, b = 2, c = 3}` Of course, let me know if I'm wrong in either or both cases.

Anyways, my question lies in how we index the entries in either of these cases. For example, let's say I have the following code:

```
local t = {"TestEntry"}
print(t["TestEntry"])
```

Of course, this prints `nil`. However, when we use a dictionary the same way:

```
local t = {TestEntry = 1}
print(t["TestEntry"])
```

This, naturally, prints `1`. My question is, why does it work this way for dictionaries, but not arrays?

Finally, I'd like to address the issue that led me to this question. Let's say, before I want to run a chunk of code, I need to see if a specific value is inside a table. It would be convenient if I could just check if it is in the table with `table["GivenEntry"]`, but, as we have seen, this would only work if the entry in the table is actually an object. In my specific case, I am simply using an array, so it is not an object.

Thus, I had to resort to using a `for` loop to check the table:

```
local t = {"TestEntry1","TestEntry2"}

for i,v in pairs(t) do
    if v == "TestEntry1" then
        --do code
    end
end
```

After doing this, it almost seemed as if it would be easier to create a silly dictionary, like:

```
local t = {TestEntry1 = "TestEntry1"}
```

because then, I could simply run `t["TestEntry1"]`, and I wouldn't have to worry about having an empty table (because then the `for` loop would not run). Are there ramifications to creating a dictionary for such purposes? Is it less efficient in general?

Your input is appreciated,
Thank you.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/7927877/107090

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Lua both arrays an dictionaries are the same type (the table). `local t = {"TestEntry"}` is essentially short for `local t = {[1] = "TestEntry"}` (The brackets are needed by Lua for a number, you would access it with `t[1]`).

So the options for checking if "TestEntry1" is in the table are as you have written. A dictionary takes more memory and depending on how many values you have may take a while to create, but accessing a key should be constant time. Whereas to loop through the table will take longer and longer the more items you have so it is a tradeoff you have to decide on.

There are faster ways to search an array however (e.g. if it is sorted: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm)