# Chek table for string.find

Tags: lua, garrys-mod

How I can check table for string.find?

My code:

```
WEAPON_TABLE = { -- I need check this weaponclass of sweps
    "swep_1",
    "swep_2",
    "swep_3"
}

if string.find(v:GetWeaponClass(), ???) then
    --
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
WEAPON_TABLE = {
    ["swep_1"]=true,
    ["swep_2"]=true,
    ["swep_3"]=true,
}

if WEAPON_TABLE[v:GetWeaponClass()] then
```

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7925090/lua-find-a-key-from-a-value