# How do I find the number of a specific item in a lua table?

Tags: lua

I have a table

```
myTable = {
    {"apple","10"},
    {"banana","20"},
    {"carrot","30"}
}
```

Is there specific lua code that can find what item number "apple" is?
Or would I have to check every single item in the myTable table to find "apple"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7925090/lua-find-a-key-from-a-value

Answer (score 2):

If you do this a single time you can use a loop like this:

```
for i,v in ipairs(myTable) do
  if v[1] == "apple" then
    print("found apple at index " .. i)
  end
end
```

If you do this multiple times for various strings you can create a look up table so you only have to traverse the table once.

```
local lut = {}
for i, v in ipairs(myTable) do
  lut[v[1]] = i
end

local appleIndex = lut.apple
local carrotIndex = lut.carrot
```