# Time complexity of table.find in Lua

Tags: lua, roblox, luau

What time complexity does the Lua function: `table.find(t, v)` have?

I am unable to find a solution from open source.

Answer (score 4):

Lua does not have a `table.find`. Many utility libraries implement a `table.find` though. Roblox's Luau has a `table.find` as well.

All of these have in common that the table `t` is a list - that is, the keys are subsequent integers >= 1 - and the elements must not be sorted. This means `table.find` can not use a binary search (O(log n)) or hash lookup (O(1)) but must use a linear search in O(n) average & worst case time.

If you want the O(1) hash map performance, use your keys as table keys rather than inserting them into a list. You can keep both a list and a hash map if order matters.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/7927877/107090

Comment: @kingerman88 It was mentioned, and also, it's spelled Luau with lowercase `u`.