Getting the key a value was assigned to in a table in lua
So I'm trying to make a table of all the creatures in a game, each creature consisting of a table with their stats. I used the creature's name as the key in the first table, but now I need to get that name, but I'm not sure how/if you can do that?
local creatureArray = {["White Wyrm"]= {
    ["dungeon"]= "Cavernam",
    ["slayer"]= "Beastial",
    ["difficulty"]= 100.8,
    ["goldvalue"]= 1008,
    ["hits"]= 4500,
    ["mindmg"]= 45,
    ["maxdmg"]= 55,
    ["wrestling"]= 105,
    ["armor"]= 50,
    ["magicresist"]= 25,
    ["ai"]= "Melee",
    ["speed"]= "Medium",
    ["uniquescaler"]= 1.35
},
}

In the example above when I iterate over this entry in the "creatureArray" I need to get the "White Wyrm" value, or the key that the sub-table is assigned to? I feel like the answer must be really simple, but I've found it hard to find answers because I'm referring to tables inside tables and probably using the wrong terminology to begin with.
For those who were wondering the game is Ultima Online Outlands, I have no affiliation with them, I'm just working on a Lua module to hopefully integrate into their community-run wiki.
I tried just referencing the table since I'm using a for loop to iterate over all of the creatures:
for i, creature in pairs(creatureArray)
In this example I tried just using "creature", but that references the table object itself and not the key.
I'm know I could add a value under each creature called "name", but that just seems redundant.

I know this doesn't address your question, but you might consider putting all of that data into a database file (SQL or CSV or JSON or similar).  Otherwise, it's going to be a pain to add additional entries.

See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7925090/lua-find-a-key-from-a-value

Assign the table is a good choice, for example in the Factorio each object has own values and the value object.prototype, that contains all properties that must be not changed, always same for all objects of this type.

@TimRoberts I'm a little limited as I'm working with a MediaWiki lua module, I should've mentioned that.

[https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Scribunto]

for i, creature in pairs(creatureArray)

When looping through a table or dictionary, it returns a key/value pair. The i is considered the key, and the creature is considered the value.
Here's an example:
local t = {
    ["Item"] = "Value",
    ["Another Item"] = "Another Value",
}

for i, value in pairs(t) do
    print(i, value)
end

The output would be:
Item            Value
Another Item    Another Value


However, the OP is a little too vague. I can't really determine if OP wants to find the key depending on the value, or just grabbing the key.

That's exactly what I was looking for, I just needed the key, thank you! Lua table terminology still confuses me a little, I knew that the second variable in the for loop was the value, but I didn't realize that the first was the key! I always called it the index, which after thinking about it, the key is a number by default! No wonder when I tried use it in the past it gave errors about it being a string
